# what is the difference between commerce order table and commerce line item table?

Tags: datetime, commerce

which table should i consider for created date for an order in commerce_order table and commerce_line_item table.

I can see created dates in both the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `commerce_order` table stores data *about an order*. The `commerce_line_item` table stores line items (e.g. products, fees, misc charges) *in that order*.

If you need to track when the order was created, reference `commerce_order.created`. If you need to track when the line item was originally added to an order, reference `commerce_line_item.created`.

Comment: Thanks Shawn..I have a strange problem with commerce_order table.If a user creates an order and he does not completes the payment process , then the order is stored in the cart. If the same user after some time creates  another order and completes the payment process then the created date stored in the table is the created date of order stored in the cart(previous order date). How to solve this problem ?

Comment: That's by design, as long as the user's session is active his cart order persists. To cover that scenario you should check the `commerce_order.changed` column, or if you need a more precise record `commerce_order_revision.revision_timestamp`.